# A conjecture about the measure estimates of a trigonometric polynomial

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, measure-theory, trigonometric-polynomials

**Formulation of the Conjecture**

Let $\Omega =(0,\pi)\times (0,2\pi)\subset\mathbb R^2$ and let $\psi:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$\psi(x,t)=\sum_{k\in S \,j\in S'} \sin(kx)\left( a_{kj}\sin(jt)+b_{kj}\cos(jt)\right),$$ where $\int_\Omega \psi^2 = 1$ and $S,S'\subset \mathbb N$ are finite subsets of $\mathbb N$.

*Note: $\psi$ is a given and fixed trigonometric polynomial with norm in $L^2(\Omega)$ equal to 1. For the conjecture $\Omega$ could be other region, for example $(0,2\pi)^2$, and $\psi$ could be a more general trigonometric polynomial. But this simpler case is the case we are interested in.*

There are $\epsilon_0,\alpha>0$ such that if $\epsilon\in(0,\epsilon_0)$, then $$\mu(\{(x,t)\in\Omega\,:\,|\psi(x,t)|<\epsilon\})<\epsilon^\alpha$$

where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue Measure in $\mathbb R^2$.

**Experimental Approach**

[Here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/asanjuanc/wavenotebooks/blob/master/conjeture.ipynb) is an IPython notebook I made with the corresponding experimentation

**Related Previous Works**

- [This paper](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~carbery/analysis/papers/cw-vc.pdf) is about Van Der Corput's Lemma in higher dimension. We don't know how to apply It.
- [This paper](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2010/182/download/) is about polynomials in random variables. We don't know how to use It eather in this case.

**Ideas given by experts**

Experts in orthogonal polynomials recommended the use of Chebyshev Polynomials. But it seems to be a not very obvious problem.

**Question**

¿How to prove the conjecture exposed above?

Comment: Editing: I think that you need encompassing parentheses after $\Sigma$. And a factorization would make the formula a bit easier to grasp visually.

Comment: Can you please review the new formulation of the question to see if It is more understandable?

Comment: Can't you simply take $\beta=1$ and then assert that the measure is bounded by $M\epsilon^{\alpha}$ for $\alpha <1$ and $\epsilon$ small enough?  (All I've done is call $\epsilon^{\beta}$ as $\epsilon$.)  This might be a little bit clearer.  In any case, the question does seem reasonable to me, and I'll add my vote to reopen.

Comment: Yes, you can take $\beta=1$. Moreover, you can take $M=1$ in this case we have that there is $\alpha\in(0,1)$ such that $\mu(E_1)<\epsilon^\alpha$.

Comment: So why not edit to make the question clear.  Having many unnecessary variables can be distracting.

Comment: You are right. I edited the question to make it clearer. Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't $(\sin x)(\sin 2t) - (\sin 2x) (\sin t)$ give a counter example? (Normalize this suitably to get $L^2$ norm $1$.  The point is that if $x$ and $y$ are less than $\epsilon^{1/4}$ each, then the answer is still $\ll \epsilon$, so that the set of small values has measure about $\epsilon^{1/2}$ (and not $\epsilon^{\alpha}$ for any $\alpha<1$).

Comment: I'll let my comment above stand.  But the question now is slightly different since you just need some $\alpha$ rather than any $\alpha <1$ (which was unclear before).  Also you may want to clarify if $\alpha$ is allowed to depend on the size of the sets $S$ and $S'$.

Comment: In the previous case $\alpha$ and $\beta$ were arbitrary with the condition $0<\alpha<\beta<1$. In this case I have to find $\alpha$ (0.001 will work fot that polynomial). I think they are equivalent problems but the last one has less variables as you requested.

Comment: $\alpha$ and $\epsilon_0$ will depend on the degree of the polynomial (the size of $S$ and $S'$) I think this is unavoidable. This is suggested in the pappers referenced above. But for now I'll be ok with a proof of the existence of $\alpha$ witout referencing it's order depending on the degree of $\psi$ if It is no possible to find.

Comment: It seems to me that you are asking for a two-dimensional version of the Nazarov-Turan inequality (see Wikipedia: take $J$ to be the whole set and $E$ the set on which $|\psi|<\varepsilon$, then rearrange and take the power $1/(n-1)$). I suggest asking Fedya Narazov. He's a regular contributor here, so he might just turn up spontaneously.

Comment: Thanks Ian. It seems It could help. Maybe with this too http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021904505002340. I'll work on that to see what happen.

Comment: Thank you, Arturo. At least in my case, I welcome your editing.

Comment: I think it should follow rather easily from the Kaloshin-Rodnianski estimate.

Comment: I didn't find it. Do you have a reference?

Comment: http://www2.math.umd.edu/~vkaloshi/papers/dioph-SO3.pdf

Comment: I whipped through the paper and I don't see how. It isn't obvious to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is based on the suggestion of [Ian](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1840/ian-morris). First we need an extension of the Nazarov-Turán Lema in infinite dimentions. It can be found [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021904505002340).

The formulation of the Nazarov-Turán Lema in higher dimensions is the following:

(Nazarov-Turán Lemma) Let $p:\mathbb T^n\to\mathbb C$ a trigonometric polynomial definded by $$ p(\boldsymbol z)=\sum_k c_k\boldsymbol z^{r_k}.$$

The index $k$ of the polynomial is given by $k=(k_1,\dots,k_n)$
for $0\leq k_i\leq m_i$ donde $m_i\in \mathbb N$. The exponents $r_k$ are defined by
$(r_{1,k_1},\dots,r_{n,k_n})$ where $r_{i,0}<\dots<r_{i,m_i}\in \mathbb Z$. We take $z^{r_k}:=z_1^{r_{1,k_1}}\dots z_{n}^{r_{n,k_n}}$. Suppose that $c_k\neq 0$ for every $k$.

Let $E\subset \mathbb T^n$ a measurable set with $\tilde\mu(E)>0$, where $\tilde\mu$ is the Haar measure on $\mathbb T^n$ ($\tilde\mu(\mathbb T^n)=1$). Then $$\sup_{\boldsymbol z\in\mathbb T^n}{|p(\boldsymbol z)|}\leq \Big(\frac{14n}{\tilde\mu(E)}\Big)^{m_1+\cdots+m_n}\sup_{\boldsymbol z \in E}{|p(\boldsymbol
z)|} .$$

The conjecture is an inmediate consecuence of this Lemma. Let's prove it:

*Proof*: Let $\tilde\psi:\mathbb T^2\to\mathbb R$ the natural periodic extension of $\psi:\Omega\to \mathbb R$. Because of the equivalence of norms in finite dimensional spaces, there is a $c>0$ such that $\|\psi\|_\infty = c$. Define $$E:=\{(x,t)\in\mathbb T^2\,:\,|\tilde \psi(x,t)|<\epsilon\}.$$

Applying the Nazarov-Turán Lemma with $n=2$ we have
$$\mu(E)\leq 112\pi^2\epsilon^{\frac1{(m_1+m_2)}}c^{\frac{-1}{m_1+m_2}},$$
where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.

It's clear that $\mu(\{(x,t)\in\Omega\,:\,|\psi(x,t)|<\epsilon\})\leq \mu(E)$. Taking $\alpha>0$ and $$\alpha<\frac{\log\Big(112\pi^2\epsilon^{\frac1{(m_1+m_2)}}c^{\frac{-1}{m_1+m_2}}\Big)}{\log(\epsilon)}$$
we obtain the desired estimation. Moreover $\alpha$ don't deppend on $\psi$